# Grab label/number from table output (R)

Tags: r, label, output

I am trying to grab the label and the values from a table() output in R.

Here is some example code:

```
a=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2)
table1=table(a)
table1
```

The output looks like this:

```
a
1    2
4    6
```

I want to be able to grab either the 1 or 2 and assign that label as a value of another variable.  I also want to be able to do this with either the 4 or 6.

I've done the following so far:

```
var1=table1[1]
var2=table1[2]
var3=var1+var2
var3
```

Output:

```
1
10
```

Is there a way to grab the value of 10 without the label of 1 above it in the output?  Also, how would I just grab the label 1 on its own?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can wrap with `as.vector` to remove the attributes

```
as.vector(var3)
#[1] 10
```

To grab the label, it would be

```
names(var3)
#[1] "1"
```